# how to convert powerpoint into images

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerpoint

I want to convert powerpoint into images when a user uploads it to my server. What is the best way of doing it?

I was using interop, but it seems to be working only on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can start PowerPoint with the [/M switch](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/powerpoint-help/command-line-switches-for-powerpoint-2007-and-the-powerpoint-viewer-2007-HA010153889.aspx) and specify a macro. The macro should contain a "Save As Other Formats" command that saves to the image format you require - I'd suggest PNG or JPEG. The macro can also exit from PowerPoint when it completes.

PowerPoint might not run well on a server; it will probably leave a hung instance if it tries to display an error box without having an attached display. It will definitely give the best looking results.